# SQLAlchemy does not update/expire model instances with external changes

Tags: python, database, caching, orm, sqlalchemy

Recently I came across strange behavior of SQLAlchemy regarding refreshing/populating model instances with the the changes that were made outside of the current session. I created the following minimal working example and was able to reproduce problem with it.

```py
from time import sleep

from sqlalchemy import orm, create_engine, Column, BigInteger, Integer
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

DATABASE_URI = "postgresql://{user}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{name}".format(
    user="postgres",
    password="postgres",
    host="127.0.0.1",
    name="so_sqlalchemy",
    port="5432",
)


class SQLAlchemy:
    def __init__(self, db_url, autocommit=False, autoflush=True):
        self.engine = create_engine(db_url)
        self.session = None

        self.autocommit = autocommit
        self.autoflush = autoflush

    def connect(self):
        session_maker = orm.sessionmaker(
            bind=self.engine,
            autocommit=self.autocommit,
            autoflush=self.autoflush,
            expire_on_commit=True
        )
        self.session = orm.scoped_session(session_maker)

    def disconnect(self):
        self.session.flush()
        self.session.close()
        self.session.remove()
        self.session = None


BaseModel = declarative_base()


class TestModel(BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = "test_models"

    id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    field = Column(Integer, nullable=False)


def loop(db):
    while True:
        with db.session.begin():
            t = db.session.query(TestModel).with_for_update().get(1)
            if t is None:
                print("No entry in db, creating...")
                t = TestModel(id=1, field=0)
                db.session.add(t)
                db.session.flush()

            print(f"t.field value is {t.field}")
            t.field += 1
            print(f"t.field value before flush is {t.field}")
            db.session.flush()
            print(f"t.field value after flush is {t.field}")

        print(f"t.field value after transaction is {t.field}")
        print("Sleeping for 2 seconds.")
        sleep(2.0)


def main():
    db = SQLAlchemy(DATABASE_URI, autocommit=True, autoflush=True)
    db.connect()
    try:
        loop(db)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Canceled")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

My `requirements.txt` file looks like this:

```
alembic==1.0.10
psycopg2-binary==2.8.2
sqlalchemy==1.3.3
```

If I run the script (I use Python 3.7.3 on my laptop running Ubuntu 16.04), it will nicely increment a value every two seconds as expected:

```
t.field value is 0
t.field value before flush is 1
t.field value after flush is 1
t.field value after transaction is 1
Sleeping for 2 seconds.
t.field value is 1
t.field value before flush is 2
t.field value after flush is 2
t.field value after transaction is 2
Sleeping for 2 seconds.
...
```

Now at some point I open postgres database shell and begin another transaction:

```
so_sqlalchemy=# BEGIN;
BEGIN
so_sqlalchemy=# UPDATE test_models SET field=100 WHERE id=1;
UPDATE 1
so_sqlalchemy=# COMMIT;
COMMIT
```

As soon as I press `Enter` after the `UPDATE` query, the script blocks as expected, as I'm issuing `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` query there. However, when I commit the transaction in the database shell, script **continues from the previous value** (say, `27`) and **does not detect** that external transaction has changed the value of `field` in database to `100`.

My question is, why does this happen at all? There are several factors that seem to contradict the current behavior:

1. I'm using `expire_on_commit` setting set to `True`, which seems to imply that every model instance that has been used in transaction will be marked as `expired` after the transaction has been committed. (Quoting [documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.__init__), "When True, all instances will be fully expired after each commit(), so that all attribute/object access subsequent to a completed transaction will load from the most recent database state.").
2. I'm not accessing some old model instance but rather issue completely new query every time. As far as I understand, this should lead to direct query to the database and not access cached instance. I can confirm that this is indeed the case if I turn sqlalchemy debug log on.

The quick and dirty fix for this problem is to call `db.session.expire_all()` right after the transaction has begun, but this seems very inelegant and counter-intuitive. I would be very glad to understand what's wrong with the way I'm working with sqlalchemy here.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a very similar situation with MySQL. I needed to "see" changes to the table that were coming from external sources in the middle of my code's database operations. I ended up having to set [autocommit=True](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_transaction.html#session-autocommit) in my session call and use the begin() / commit() methods of the session to "see" data that was updated externally.

The SQLAlchemy docs say this is a legacy configuration:

> Warning
>
> “autocommit” mode is a legacy mode of use and should not be considered for new projects.

but also say in the next paragraph:

> Modern usage of “autocommit mode” tends to be for framework integrations that wish to control specifically when the “begin” state occurs

So it doesn't seem to be clear which statement is correct.